# Java - How to test some code?

Tags: java, testing, junit, data-conversion

I am not looking for the answer to this question but just a brief outline of how to do it. This is a question from a exam past paper.

It states: Describe in English a sequence of tests that you might use to test code to implement the `NumberCoversion` class. Your tests should cover all the conditions described in the above definition.

I won't write the specification of the class but it contains things like: it must take `String` as input and output, accepting two parameters and returning `null` if a number is not valid etc.

The question is worth 10% so will I just be required to write a series of things like: Ensure that the constructor only accepts two parameters of type int, and not anything else e.g. double or accept 3 parameters.

Would it be worth writing possible JUnit test methods in English/Pseudocode.

Would this be the right sort of thing to write for tests in English?

Comment: it depend on your professor how he wants the test cases.

Comment: He wants test cases in English.

Comment: "Describe in English ..." IMO, it's only looking for an explanation not the code.

Comment: I'd write pseudo code if I were you. It is a good way of explaining your intent. A lot more clear than writing English sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the goal is to describe a test case which checks each of the specifications in the question, whilst also avoiding attempting to test things which are limited by the language construct (e.g. wrong number/type of arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Describe in English what you will do if you write tests. Typically it's usage of the `NumberConversion` class.

Answer (score 1):

According to the question, you need to describe tests in English. I think that jumping to JUnit unit tests is more than being asked for. If I answered this question, I would start by looking at the definition given of the `NumberConversion` class. I would describe tests that use valid inputs as well as tests that use invalid ones. For each test describe how you will ensure that the `NumberConversion` class behaves as expected, including expected error conditions.

Answer (score 1):

As an example for what might be appropriate...

If the specifications were:

- Takes a string as input
- The string can be an arbitrarily large non-negative integer
- If the string is not a non-negative integer, an exception is thrown

Then I would probably answer something along the lines of:

- I would test with "42" as input to check that the method works with a "normal" number
- I would test with "0" as input to check that the method works with the edge case number
- I would test with "9223372036854775808" (1 more than Long.MAX_VALUE) as input to check that the method works with a number larger than the fixed length integers provided by Java
- I would test with "-1" as input and ensure that an exception is thrown, as negative input is invalid
- I would test witht "0xa" as input and ensure that an exception is thrown, as hexadecimal input is invalid
- I would test witht "0.1" as input and ensure that an exception is thrown, as non integral input is invalid